# 1 table = 1 class + 1 one of 2 abstract class

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have two tables which looks something like this

```
Table Queue
 int ID;
 string Name;
 int MessageID;
 string To
 string From
 string Topic
 string Email

Table Message
 int ID
 int MessageType
```

This is a rather simplified version, but what we did in the classes was to create 1 class named

```
 class Queue
 int ID
 string Name
 Message message
```

And then we have an abstract message with either types of message.

```
 class abstract Message()

 class SMSMessage : Message
 string ToMobile
 string FromMobile
 string Message

 class EmailMessage
 string ToEmail
 string FromEmail
 string Topic
 string Email
```

However now my problem is figuring out how to map this with fluent Nhibernate.
How would i do this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I could rewrite the article, but I think I'll allow it to stand on its own: http://marekblotny.blogspot.com/2009/03/fluent-nhibernate-and-inheritance.html

EDIT:

Running with the spirit of the article, I'd try the following (and I really have no idea if this will work):

Write a Message map:

```
public class MessageMap : ClassMap<Message> {
  public MessageMap() {
    Id(x=>x.Id).GeneratedBy.Native();
    // only the common stuff

    DiscriminateSubClassesOnColumn<int>("MessageType")
      .SubClass<SMSMessage>(1, m=>m.HasOne( x=>{
                                                 Map(x=>x.ToMobile);
                                                 Map(x=>x.FromMobile);
                                                 // etc
                                               })
                            .Cascade.SaveUpdate()
                            .FetchType.Join())
      .SubClass<EmailMessage>(2, m=>m.HasOne(x=>{
                                                 Map(x=>x.ToEmail);
                                                 Map(x=>x.FromEmail);
                                                 // etc
                                               })
                            .Cascade.SaveUpdate()
                            .FetchType.Join())
  }
}
```

We'll do SMS only for now ...

```
public class SMSMessage : Message {
  public virtual string ToMobile { get; set; }
  public virtual string FromMobile { get; set; }
  ...
}
```

Here's the mapping class...

```
public class SMSMessageMap : ClassMap<SMSMessage> {
  public SMSMessageMap() {
    WithTable("Queue");
    Id(x=>x.Id, "QueueID").GeneratedBy.Foreign("Message");
    Map(x=>x.ToMobile, "To");
    Map(x=>x.FromMobile, "From");
    WithTable("Message", m=>
    {
      m.Map(x=>x.MessageBody);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi i just figured out that the type is actually within another table meaning we have something like this:

Table Queue
 int ID; 
 string Name; 
 int MessageID;
 string To;
 string From;
 string Topic;
 string Email

Table Message
 int ID
 int MessageType

Is there still anyway to map this ?

Comment: This wouldnt work, first you are refering to a Details property which doesnt exist, secondly you newer refer to the QueueID which is necessary to get the To and From.

Comment: The SMSMessageMap uses the Queue table and the Id(x=>x.Id) would refer to the QueueID. I didn't realize the column was named QueueID as you use "Id" in the question. .. Still not sure it's going to work. :)